# The best way to use child classes and methods

Tags: c#, class, coding-style

Have some newbie questions. 
I have 6 classes:

```
public class MainSettingsClass
{
    int a;
    int b;
}

public class SubSettingsClass_1 : MainSettingsClass
{
    int c;
}

public class SubSettingsClass_2 : MainSettingsClass
{
    int d;
}

public class ParentClass
{
    public MainSettingsClass settings;
}

public class ChildClass_1 : ParentClass
{
}

public class ChildClass_2 : ParentClass
{
}
```

Now the questions.  ChildClass_1 with SubSettingsClass_1 and ChildClass_2 with SubSettingsClass_1

```
ChildClass_1 firstClassVar = new ChildClass_1();
ChildClass_2 secondClassVar = new ChildClass_2();
SubSettingsClass_1 firstClassSettings = new SubSettingsClass_1();
SubSettingsClass_2 secondClassSettings = new SubSettingsClass_2();
firstClassVar.settings = (MainSettingsClass)firstClassSettings;
secondClassVar.settings = (MainSettingsClass)secondClassSettings;
```

The main thing that if i need get "c" variable using "firstClassVar.settings" i need everytime write:

```
 ((firstClassSettings)firstClassVar.settings).c
```

1. Is it right way to access variables?
2. Or there is a better ways exists?
3. Is this code corresponds programming rules? Or its not correct?

Sorry for bad english.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have is *technically* fine, although there's a few somewhat problematic aspects. First, there's no need to cast to `MainSettingsClass`. Since both `SubSettingsClass_1` and `SubSettingsClass_2` inherit from `MainSettingsClass`, `ParentClass`, and all derivatives thereof, will accept either as the value for a field defined as being of type `MainSettingsClass`.

Second, fields (of which `settings` is one) aren't typically made public. Properties, which have defined getters and setters are generally your interface to data on a object.

Third, `settings` here is a dependency, and as such, should really be injected via the constructor of the class. Something like:

```
public class ParentClass
{
    protected MainSettingsClass settings;

    public ParentClass(MainSettingsClass settings)
    {
        this.settings = settings;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

One more thing I just thought about that would be beneficial for you to know. Keep in mind that by using a least common denominator like `MainSettingsClass`, you lose the ability to work with specific members of the more specific derived classes `SubSettingsClass_1` and `SubSettingsClass_2`. However, generics can be used to give you a bit more flexibility:

```
public class ParentClass<TSettings>
    where TSettings : MainSettingsClass
{
    protected TSettings settings;

    public ParentClass(TSettings settings)
    {
        this.settings = settings;
    }
}

public class ChildClass_1 : ParentClass<SubSettingsClass_1>
{
    ...
}

public class ChildClass_2 : ParentClass<SubSettingsClass_2>
{
    ...
}
```

With that, you can now work with `c` in `ChildClass_1` and `d` in `ChildClass_2` because the type of your `settings` field will be `SubSettingsClass_1` and `SubSettingsClass_2`, respectively.

Comment: Thank you for catching all the terrible practice in that code I forgot to talk about. +1

Comment: Thanks thats useful too!

Answer (score 3):

1. Is that the "right" way to access the `c` variable? **No**. If you *have* to downcast, at least check it first:

   ```
   firstClassSettings derivedSettings = firstClassVar.settings as firstClassSettings;
   if (derivedSettings != nulL)
   {
       //Do whatever with derivedSettings.c
   }
   ```
2. There's a better way :) Its called *polymorphism*. Your classes are super general, so its hard to say *exactly* how your design should look, but your main class should have some method that the derived classes override to get the custom behavior.
3. Downcasting is a **huge** code-smell. Sometimes there is no way around it (especially in legacy code, or in certain `Object` overrides and WPF interfaces) but, you should avoid it if at all possible. Doubly so in your own objects/code.

Comment: Is it possible to change type of variable?
For example like:

    public class ChildClass_1 : ParentClass
    {
        public SubSettingsClass_1 settings;
    }

For example i have loop. I dont know what object Child_1 or Child_2 will be used in loop, but everytime i need to get their (share, "a" or "b") settings class variable. Child_1 objects have only Subsettings_1, Child_2 have only Subsettings_2. How to access variable "a" in this situation in loop?

Comment: @denismart Just use it as is :). The variable is already of type `MainSettingsClass`, so you can write `settings.a` safely. **Upcasting** is very common, and very safe. Its downcasting you have to be careful with.